# R Linux problem loading shared library using dyn.load

Tags: r, shared-libraries, centos7, hdf5

R demands a more recent version of HDF5 then my CentOS 7 provides, and i try to compensate for this by having installed HDF-Group's precompiled packages in "/opt/hdf5-1.12.0", side by side with CentOS7's stock HDF5 package.

But any attempt to install the package in R then fails:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8   LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8   LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C   LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics  grDevices utils datasets  methods   base 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0
```

All the steps prior to this error are jsut fine, all the pathes are correct

Digging deeper, i found i apparently can't load that library dynamically, although it exists in the referenced path:

```
> Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH = \
"/usr/lib64/R/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:\
/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:\
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/hdf5-1.12.0")
> dyn.load('/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200')
Error in dyn.load("/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200") : 
unable to load shared object '/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200':
libhdf5.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

while actually:

```
[root:  ls /opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200
lrwxrwxrwx. root root unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0   /opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200 ->; libhdf5_hl.so.200.0.0

[root:  ls /opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200.0.0 
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0   /opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200.0.0
```

Here the R session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8   LC_NUMERIC=C
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8   LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C   LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics  grDevices utils datasets  methods   base 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0
```

Filesystem permissions are the exact same as succesfully used for all other custom applications stored under /opt...

```
root$:  ls -al /opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib
total 17604
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Jul 25 20:53 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root     104 Jul 25 20:53 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   83427 Jul 25 20:53 jarhdf5-1.12.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9119168 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5.a
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  958770 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_cpp.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      22 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_cpp.so -> libhdf5_cpp.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      22 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_cpp.so.200 -> libhdf5_cpp.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  534352 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_cpp.so.200.0.0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  470268 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      26 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_fortran.so -> libhdf5_fortran.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      26 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_fortran.so.200 -> libhdf5_fortran.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  418648 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_fortran.so.200.0.0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  234954 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl.a
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   13574 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl_cpp.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      25 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      25 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.200 -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   19760 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl_fortran.a -> libhdf5hl_fortran.a
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  184756 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5hl_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      20 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl_fortran.so -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      28 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5hl_fortran.so -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      28 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5hl_fortran.so.200 -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  165800 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5hl_fortran.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      21 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl.so -> libhdf5_hl.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      21 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl.so.200 -> libhdf5_hl.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  157344 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_hl.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  604720 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5_java.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    5586 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5.settings
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      18 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5.so -> libhdf5.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      18 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5.so.200 -> libhdf5.so.200.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4851592 Jul 25 20:53 libhdf5.so.200.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      14 Jul 25 20:53 libsz.so -> libsz.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      14 Jul 25 20:53 libsz.so.2 -> libsz.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   50518 Jul 25 20:53 libsz.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      13 Jul 25 20:53 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      13 Jul 25 20:53 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.5
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  106903 Jul 25 20:53 libz.so.1.2.5
```

Does anyone can give me a hint please?

Because i am running out of ideas...

Comment: Does replacing `/opt/hdf5-1.12.0` with `/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  help to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you noticed that the error message mentions file `libhdf5.so.200` when you are trying to load `libhdf5_hl.so.200`?

Comment: Hello Gorka and Rui,
thank you for chiming in.
I even explicitely added the lib sectio to the past, but it didn't change the situation:
It struck me as well that the mentioned objects differ, but i understood this to be s.th. like a cascaded failure?
Both objects are present actually, as the listing shows which i added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

i found that preloading the libraries helped the issue:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5.so:/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so
```

Afterwards, the dynamic loading worked silently:

```
dyn.load('/opt/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.200')
```

Unfortunately i don't understand, why R seems to be not able to do this on it's own...